# equivalent of regionprops in python skimage for JuliaImages and Python opencv

Tags: python, julia, opencv3.0, scikit-image

What is the equivalent command of [regionprops](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) which you can find in Python skimage in Python opencv and/or JuliaImages?

If there is not an all-in-one command like `regionprops` then the most important properties I am looking are the label of the region,(assuming connected components have integer values) and coordinates of the labels.

Comment: Which props are you after?  There's not a all-in-one function like that; they're split apart in Julia.  See [`labeled_components`](https://juliaimages.org/latest/function_reference/#Images.label_components) and the following `component_*` methods.

Comment: See cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params at https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/ and https://answers.opencv.org/question/98889/simple-blob-detection/ and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html